# Delete where records not exists in other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-delete

I have 2 tables: Table1 (ID, Table2ID, Col1,....) and Table2 (ID, Col1,....). Table2ID is a foreign key reference from Table2. I want to write a query to delete records from Table2 where the ID (Table2ID) doesn't exist in Table1. Record counts in Table1 > 300 million and Table1 > 100 million. I have two queries in mind, but am not sure which one will be faster:

Query 1 (Didn't work):

```
delete from Table2
select ID from Table2
except
select Table2ID from Table1
```

Query 2:

```
delete from Table2
where ID not in (select distinct Table2ID from Table1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Query2 is faster

```
delete from Table2
where ID not in (select distinct Table2ID from Table1)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
select * 
into #temptable2
from table2 t2,table1 t1 
where t1.table2id = t2.id;

truncate table table2;

insert into table2
select * from #temptable2;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be faster:

```
DELETE B
FROM table1 a
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 b ON a.table2id = b.id 
WHERE b.id IS null
```

Comment: Can you explain the WHERE condition? b.ID always has value in Table2

Comment: It won't if it doesn't find b.id in table1.  Change the "delete B" to be "select *" and you'll see what's returned

Comment: yea i do that all the time it's just using a left join to get the results of those items that don't overlap